# PushbackReader without EOF?

Tags: java, file, filestream

I'm currently using [PushbackReader](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PushbackReader.html) and while waiting for where it 'supposed' to be an EOF, I get the character 65535 and I'm wondering if that's normal.

Where is my EOF?!

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java `char` is unsigned; 65535 = 0xFFFF = -1; use `int`.

Answer (score 1):

See also [this java bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=5031992) where in some JRE versions PushbackReader returns 65535 when reading an unread -1.